# provision azure ad b2c with resources in the tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, azure-ad-b2c, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following terraform code :

```hcl
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      version = ">= 3.0.2"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {}
  
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
    alias = "aad_b2c"
    tenant_id = azurerm_aadb2c_directory.example-b2c.tenant_id
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_aadb2c_directory" "example-b2c" {
  country_code            = "FR"
  data_residency_location = "Europe"
  display_name            = "example"
  domain_name             = "example.onmicrosoft.com"
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  sku_name                = "PremiumP1"
}

resource "azuread_application" "demo" {
  provider = azurerm.aad_b2c
  display_name = "demo"
}
```

I got the following message :
`The provider hashicorp/azurerm does not support resource type "azuread_application".`

According to [the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration) I cannot assigned a value which is an exported attribute to configure my  provider. Is there any workarround to create an azure AD B2C tenant and some app registration inside ?

Comment: If I remove the alias when calling the `azuread_application` it works pretty well with the first instance of `azurerm` provider

Comment: `azuread_application` is for `azuread` provider, but you are using `azuream`.

Comment: Indeed you are right, but howcome can I create an app reg if I didn't declare an azuread provider in my `terraform{}` block ?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe you it defined in some other file. Did using correct provider solved your issue?

Comment: Still testing but it sounds good so far

Comment: Ok. If you don't mind then, I will post an answer based on my comment.

Comment: Yeah please do; as usual thanks for your help marcin, as usual when it comes to terraform you're the one ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

[azuread_application](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application) is part of [azuread](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs) provider, not the [azurerm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs).